# Need a little help with rephrasing

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

So, this is the sentence:

Faustus’s annihilation is a sobering reminder of our own human shortcomings; the parable resonates throughout the ages, encouraging even us, as a modern audience, to re-evaluate the things that we are using to make ourselves happy.

And what *I'm* not happy with is the final phrase, in particular the word 'things', which sounds a bit too sloppy...

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "... to re-evaluate the means to our happiness."

How about this?

Answer (score 0):

... the way we make ourselves...?